# When calculating the factorial why does this recursive method not work?

Tags: ruby, recursion

Can someone help me understand why the code below works fine

Works:

```
def factorial(n)
  return 1 if n == 1

  n * factorial(n-1)
end

puts factorial(5)
```

But when I refactor it like so, it throws an exception: ****': nil can't be coerced into Integer (TypeError)***

Fails:

```
def factorial(n)
  puts n

  n * factorial(n-1) unless n == 1
end

factorial(5)
```

As another example, this code works fine and is written in a similar way:

Works:

```
def count_down(number)
  puts number

  count_down(number - 1) unless number == 0
end

count_down(10)
```

Comment: From my understanding it should do 5x(5-1), 5x(4-1), 5x(3-1), 5x(2-1) at which point because 1 is reached, it should stop execution

Comment: I order to calculate `2 * factorial(1)` you need the value for `factorial(1)` – what does it return? You end up with `2 * nil`, hence the error.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan makes sense now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this code works fine and is written in a similar way

No it isn’t. Your `count_down` isn’t similar at all, because it doesn’t return a value.

But your `factorial` does return a value, and each recursive call uses that value.

Well, your second example doesn’t say what to return when `n` is 1, so it returns `nil` and the call stack breaks down.

Your first example does say what to return when `n` is 1. That’s the difference.

Comment: The trouble is, of course, that Ruby functions do not define contracts. If this were Swift or some similar compiled language, your `factorial` would declare that it returns an integer, and then the compiler would complain in your second example that you are _not_ always returning an integer, and the code wouldn't even run. But of course Ruby just skips happily past all that and runs without question, and no issue arises until we actually try to perform the the `1` loop of the recursion and Ruby returns `nil` because it doesn't know what else to do. :)

Comment: Thanks @matt it now all clicks and makes sense